# Python - safe & elegant way to set a variable from function that may return None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a more elegant way of declaring a variable value where the function may return `None` and there are chained methods following the function call.

In the example below I am using BeautifulSoup to pass an HTML doc and if the element I am looking for is not found, the initial function call returns `None`. The chained methods then break the code because `.string` is not a method of `None` object.

Which all makes sense, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to write these variable declarations that won't break on a `None` value.

```
# I want to do something like this but it throws error if soup.find returns
# none because .string is not a method of None.
title = soup.find("h1", "article-title").string or "none"


# This works but is both ugly and inefficient
title = "none" if soup.find("h1", "article-title") is None else soup.find("h1", "article-title").string

# So instead I'm using this which feels clunky as well
title = soup.find("h1", "article-title")
title = "none" if title is None else title.string
```

Any better way?

Comment: I think in this case, the `try ... except AttributeError` wrap is the default (or simplest) way to solve this, in particular for a long set of chained methods.

Comment: You clearly looking for the [safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator) as it is called in Groovy. There is no such construct in Python. But I agree this could be useful, especially when you have long chain of methods call potentially returning None. @Evert the one problem with the `try ... except AttributeError...` solution is you cannot distinguish between an exception generated from one of the chained method returning `None` and a "real" exception raised by one called method (i.e.: it will "hide" `AttributeError`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function to provide a default value in case the desired attribute is not found within a given object:

```
title = getattr(soup.find("h1", "article-title"), "string", "none")
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`try statement`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=try#the-try-statement):

```
try:
    title = soup.find("h1", "article-title").string
except AttributeError:
    title = "none"
```

The first method is more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: Using `getattr` is indeed a solution when accessing data attributes (as in OP example). But it does not solve the issue more generally when calling _"chained methods"_ (as stated by the OP too). Or do I missed something ?

Comment: I think I'll use try/except as while it's less elegant it's dead clear what it's purpose is. And as @SylvainLeroux states getattr won't work with actual chained methods which I am using for other vars as well. But great to know about getattr too. Thanks.

Comment: @patns Well, as you likely know, in Python, functions are just values that you can pass around freely. So even if you want to do a "chained method call" like `obj.call1().call2().call3()`, you can still do so with `getattr(getattr(getattr(obj, "call1", dfn1)(), "call2", dfn2)(), "call3", dfn3)()`. Just define your "default" functions and pass them around by their name.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Chained methods means stuff like `obj.call1().call2.call3()`? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Shashank Yes, you're right. Of course, you can "chain" member access by _nesting_ `getattr` -- but I wouldn't qualify that as ... hum ... "elegant". Nevertheless, this is currently the most functional option. And it is more interesting than the `try ... except AttributeError` option that would have the major drawback of hiding an `AttributeError` potentially raised by one of the called method.

Answer (score 4):

I like Shashank's answer, but this might work for you as well:

```
class placeholder:
    string = "none"

title = (soup.find("h1", "article-title") or placeholder).string
```

Answer (score 2):

This behavior of Beautiful Soup really annoys me as well. Here's my solution: http://soupy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

This smooths over lots of edge cases in BeautifulSoup, allowing you to write queries like

```
dom.find('h1').find('h2').find('a')['href'].orelse('not found').val()
```

Which returns what you're looking for if it exists, or 'not found' otherwise.

The general strategy in soupy is to wrap the data you care about in thin wrapper classes. A simple example of such a wrapper:

```
class Scalar(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return Scalar(getattr(self._val, key, None))
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Scalar(self._val(*args, **kwargs))
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Scalar(%s)' % self._val


s = Scalar('hi there')
s.upper()  # Scalar('HI THERE')
s.a.b.c.d  # Scalar(None)
```

If you want to be fancy about it, the mathematical property that lets you safely chain things forever is *closure* (ie methods return instances of the same type). Lots of BeautifulSoup methods don't have this property, which is what soupy addresses.